# How can I get total number of refunded quantity for each product?

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show refunded quantity for each product/ID by using WordPress WPDB feature. But I can't make it. Can someone help me with that, please?

Here Is some code I have tried but none of this worked:-

```
SELECT order_id FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta woim 
        LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items oi 
        ON woim.order_item_id = oi.order_item_id 
        WHERE meta_key = '_product_id' AND meta_value = 5734
        GROUP BY order_id



SELECT * FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta woim JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items oi JOIN wp_posts wp_pos ON woim.order_item_id = oi.order_item_id WHERE meta_key = '_product_id' AND meta_value = 5734 and wp_pos.post_status='wc-refunded'


SELECT * FROM `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` WHERE `meta_key`='_product_id' AND `meta_value`='5734'


SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type`='shop_order' AND `post_status`='wc-refunded'



SELECT * FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta woim 
         JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items oi 
       JOIN wp_posts wp_po 
        ON woim.order_item_id = oi.order_item_id 
        WHERE meta_key = '_product_id' AND meta_value = 5734 and wp_po.post_type='shop_order' AND wp_po.post_status='wc-refunded'
```

Comment: Not write SQL, just write your orignal data and what result you want.We will give you     
 a SQL.

Comment: @Shawn.X I want to get the total refunded quantity for each product. Such as, I have a product with ID=1111 and it's refunded in 4 times. So  I want the 4 as my result.

Comment: You are going to need to show us an example dataset. How do wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta and wp_woocommerce_orders and wp_posts look like, what columns, what do those columns represent